# Access to content disposition header in php/server

Tags: php, apache, header

I am doing some debugging in php and I need to take a look at the full headers sent to the server in including the multipart form-data information stored in content disposition.

However apache_request_headers() doesn't return that information.

Any clues?

---

I am also happy to look at a non php solution if possible

Answer (score 0):

From PHP Docs:

> Note: As of PHP 4.3.3 you can use this
>   function with the NSAPI server module
>   in Netscape/iPlanet/SunONE webservers,
>   too.

Make sure that those requirements are met.

You can also get the complete header info with feature-rich **[httpWatch](http://www.httpwatch.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=banner_220&utm_content=debug&utm_campaign=stackoverflow_0609)** program out there.

Comment: Yes I get output from the apache header function but not the content disposition value. Also httpWatch is client side, I need a server side solution

Answer (score 0):

Also not PHP related, but you can see the complete request header along with the responses in any Webkit browser (Safari, Chrome) via the Resources-tab in the developer tool. And for Firefox, there's the [FireBu](http://getfirebug.com/network)g-addon, which offers the same functionality.

Comment: Sadly the issue is very intermittent and is on a clients machine so we need to log it on the server side.